# How to stick an elemet to different size of image on carousel

Tags: html, css

I have a carousel with different sized of images but they all have the same height (500px).

On this pictures I want to put the navigations button (prev and next) at the bottom left.

I succeeded to put the navigation buttons where I want on the vertical axe because the height of pictures is fix but still struggling for the horizontal axe

This is what looks like the code actually

```
<div class="carousel" ng-controller="CarouselController as $ctrl">
  <img ng-show="$ctrl.currentIndex == 0"/>
  <img ng-show="$ctrl.currentIndex == 1"/>
  <img ng-show="$ctrl.currentIndex == 2"/>
  <img ng-show="$ctrl.currentIndex == 3"/>

  <div class="carousel-navigation">
    <a ng-click="$ctrl.showPrevious()"> <
    <a ng-click="$ctrl.showNext()" > >
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.carousel{
 position: relative;
 .carousel-navigation {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0
 }
}
```

Do you have any idea how I can do that by avoiding javascript ?

EDIT:
[image: Here is what I try to do]

EDIT2: On the picture the big square is the `<div class='carousel'>`, then the square under title is the `<img/>`and the plain black square is `<div class="carousel">`. The next big square is just showing what it should look like after clicking on next when the `img` is less width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Left" css property.

**Edit : You can use flex property.**
(jQuery is just for changing the pictures)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button1').click(function(){
    $('img').attr('src', 'https://picsum.photos/300/300?random=1');
  });
  $('#button2').click(function(){
    $('img').attr('src', 'https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1');
  });
});
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .image-container{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container .image-container img{
  width: 100;
  height: auto;
}

.container .image-container .navigation{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  left: 0;
  
  /* styling */
  background-color: SlateBlue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span class="image-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" alt="">
    <div class="navigation">
       Navigation
    </div>
  </span>
</div>

<button id="button1">Image 1</button>
<button id="button2">Image 2</button>
```

Comment: But this will put my container-navigation at the left of the container not of the image so if I have an image with a smaller width the container-navigation will be out

Comment: Hi, you can use Flex to do it. I edited my answer.